# ListView adding items

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Okay, first off, i started (trying) to learn Java about 2 days ago.
im trying to make an application that lists all installed applications (activityInfo.loadLabel)
and i want to launch the application on item click (activityInfo.packageName)
i have these stored in a list of AppItems

```
class AppItem{
    String _appname;
    public String getAppname(){return _appname;};
    public void setAppname(String value){_appname = value;};
    String _app;
    public String getApp(){ return _app; };
    public void setApp(String value){_app = value; };
}
```

I can add an array of strings to my listview just fine.
but how do i add 2 different values to the same row (so to speak) in a listview - in Java.
please tell me if you dont understand my question - and il'l try to elaborate best possible

here is my code:

```
ArrayList<AppItem> apps;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        AppItem appItem = new AppItem();
        for (ResolveInfo applicationInfo : pkgAppsList) {
            appItem._appname = (String) applicationInfo.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
            appItem._app= applicationInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            apps.add(appItem);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<AppItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,apps);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);     
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         setContentView(listView);

         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();            
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
class AppItem{
    String _appname;
    public String getAppname(){return _appname;};
    public void setAppname(String value){_appname = value;};
    String _app;
    public String getApp(){ return _app; };
    public void setApp(String value){_app = value; };
}
```

or
is there an alternative to using

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

would i be able to start an application via its label name?

Comment: i don't understand why you need 2 items in the same row

Comment: well i need the Text as the label - and i need to call the packagename so i can get the application to start - unless there's a way to start an application by its label? in c# i would have used the Text field and description field or something like that, so i could get the description of the selected item

Comment: follow the link[follow the link](http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps-in-style/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayAdapter displays the content of `AppItem.toString()` in the layout you give it.

You can override toString() to display the label:

```
public void toString() {
    return _appName;
}
```

in the onItemClick, you can get the item by calling

```
AppItem item = (AppItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

or, given that appItem is accessible (either final or a field of your activity rather than a local variable to the method)

```
apps.get(position);
```

You can then have the package and call the activity :

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(item.getAapp());
```

Comment: unfortunatly overriding the toString did not work
@override
public String toString(){return _appname;} right? - if i manually enter the return value, it returns that value, but if i use "_appname" it returns the last application on the list 400 times -.-
but if add an arraylist with .loadlabel it adds the labels just fine - am i not storing the values correctly?

Comment: my bad - created a new instance of appitem inside the loop - and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define own layout for the row (which can hold any number of elements) and then override `getView()` in your adapter, inflate your layout and return it when listview ask for it. This gives you ability to make each row look as you want, or have each row different depending on data type (it absolutely up to you what your `getView()` returns - list view will just display what adapter retuns). I am not giving any code here as literally any Android ListView tutorial will give you that as this is quite fundamental.

Randomly spotted tutorials: [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) or [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)